# searching and printing word path with shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

```
$ df -gt /gcif
Filesystem    GB blocks      Used      Free %Used Mounted on
/dev/gcifnewlv     50.00     30.57     19.43   62% /gcif
$ df -gt /gcif|awk '{print $1}'|grep dev
/dev/gcifnewlv
```

Now I want only **gcifnewlv** from above example and stored it in a variable.
How I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
export my_var=$(df -gt /gcif|awk '{print $1}'|grep dev)
```

to write the output to a variable.

If you just want `gcifnewlv` from `/dev/gcifnewlv`, you could use:

```
df -gt /gcif|awk '{print $1}'|grep dev|rev|cut -d/ -f 1|rev
```

Comment: There is something missing in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
var=$(df -gt /gcif | grep -oP '(?<=/dev/)gcifnewlv')
```